# studio.exe of Android studio does not open, Windows 10 32-Bit

Tags: java, android-studio, installation

I want to install Android Studio on my 32-Bit Computer running Windows 10, but studio.exe in the bin folder won't open. I've set both system variables `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\` and set `PATH` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\`.
I've also tried to run it as an administrator. I receive the following LOG-File when I try to open it:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x1a7a2ee5, pid=3156, tid=0x000013d8
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_152-b02) (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (25.152-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x1a7a2ee5
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x05a17000):  JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5080, stack(0x06000000,0x06100000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x00000008 0x1a7a2ee5

Registers:
EAX=0x00000001, EBX=0x05a17130, ECX=0x060ff7dc, EDX=0x77d60750
ESP=0x060ff80c, EBP=0x060ff838, ESI=0x00000001, EDI=0x00009829
EIP=0x1a7a2ee5, EFLAGS=0x00010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x060ff80c)
0x060ff80c:   00030602 00009829 00000001 00b798a0
0x060ff81c:   77cfbb73 05a17130 77d036a6 060ff808
0x060ff82c:   060ff940 524b9fd8 00000001 060ff864
0x060ff83c:   776c5267 00030602 00009829 524a5100
0x060ff84c:   fffffffe 00009829 dcbaabcd 00000001
0x060ff85c:   00030602 00009829 060ff950 776a185c
0x060ff86c:   524a7ed0 00030602 00009829 524a5100
0x060ff87c:   fffffffe 3b890e32 060ff9e8 00b798a0 

Instructions: (pc=0x1a7a2ee5)
0x1a7a2ec5:   00 00 00 01 00 00 00 e8 f4 97 03 c4 64 be 71 80
0x1a7a2ed5:   07 59 1a 80 0a 97 19 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 e8
0x1a7a2ee5:   f4 97 03 43 a8 97 8c 90 09 59 1a 80 0a 97 19 00
0x1a7a2ef5:   00 00 00 01 00 00 00 e8 f4 97 03 c1 f8 4e 6d c0 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000001 is an unknown value
EBX=0x05a17130 is an unknown value
ECX=0x060ff7dc is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x05a17000
EDX=0x77d60750 is an unknown value
ESP=0x060ff80c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x05a17000
EBP=0x060ff838 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x05a17000
ESI=0x00000001 is an unknown value
EDI=0x00009829 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x06000000,0x06100000],  sp=0x060ff80c,  free space=1022k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x1a7a2ee5
C  [USER32.dll+0x35267]
C  [USER32.dll+0x1185c]
C  [USER32.dll+0x10df3]
C  [USER32.dll+0x10c30]
C  [awt.dll+0xa7b54]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop()V+0
j  sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run()V+58
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x05a17000 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5080, stack(0x06000000,0x06100000)]
  0x05a16800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=3800, stack(0x05f00000,0x06000000)]
  0x05a15400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9752, stack(0x05e00000,0x05f00000)]
  0x03e3ec00 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9868, stack(0x04850000,0x04950000)]
  0x03ddfc00 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1728, stack(0x04750000,0x04850000)]
  0x03ddf000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4560, stack(0x04650000,0x04750000)]
  0x03dee400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8472, stack(0x04550000,0x04650000)]
  0x03ded800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3976, stack(0x04450000,0x04550000)]
  0x03dea800 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1352, stack(0x04350000,0x04450000)]
  0x03dc5c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5132, stack(0x04130000,0x04230000)]
  0x03db0c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3168, stack(0x04030000,0x04130000)]
  0x01c1d000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=6732, stack(0x00050000,0x00150000)]

Other Threads:
  0x03da9400 VMThread [stack: 0x03f30000,0x04030000] [id=8344]
  0x03e32c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x04950000,0x04a50000] [id=3248]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 67854K [0x17600000, 0x1f600000, 0x1f600000)
  eden space 104960K,  52% used [0x17600000, 0x1ab83b40, 0x1dc80000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x1e940000, 0x1f600000, 0x1f600000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x1dc80000, 0x1dc80000, 0x1e940000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 131072K, used 23534K [0x1f600000, 0x27600000, 0x47600000)
 Metaspace       used 6618K, capacity 6836K, committed 6912K, reserved 7552K

Card table byte_map: [0x020e0000,0x02270000] byte_map_base: 0x02025000

Marking Bits: (CMSBitMap*) 0x01910fa0
 Bits: [0x023c0000, 0x037c0000)

Mod Union Table: (CMSBitMap*) 0x01911000
 Bits: [0x004f0000, 0x00518000)

Polling page: 0x001e0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=2471Kb max_used=2471Kb free=243288Kb
 bounds [0x08490000, 0x08700000, 0x17490000]
 total_blobs=1036 nmethods=824 adapters=128
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 1.662 Thread 0x03ddfc00  777       1       java.lang.invoke.MethodTypeForm::basicType (5 bytes)
Event: 1.662 Thread 0x03ddfc00 nmethod 777 0x086e7e48 code [0x086e7f40, 0x086e7fe0]
Event: 1.672 Thread 0x03ddfc00  779       3       jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter::newClass (9 bytes)
Event: 1.672 Thread 0x03ddfc00 nmethod 779 0x086e8048 code [0x086e8160, 0x086e826c]
Event: 1.675 Thread 0x03ddfc00  780       3       java.io.BufferedReader::ensureOpen (18 bytes)
Event: 1.675 Thread 0x03ddfc00 nmethod 780 0x086e8308 code [0x086e8420, 0x086e85ac]
Event: 1.675 Thread 0x03ddfc00  781       3       javax.swing.text.html.CSSParser::readChar (25 bytes)
Event: 1.675 Thread 0x03ddfc00 nmethod 781 0x086e8648 code [0x086e8760, 0x086e890c]
Event: 1.675 Thread 0x03ddfc00  782   !   3       java.io.BufferedReader::read (104 bytes)
Event: 1.676 Thread 0x03ddfc00 nmethod 782 0x086e8ac8 code [0x086e8c40, 0x086e9178]

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 1.127 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 104960K [0x17600000, 0x1f600000, 0x1f600000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x17600000, 0x1dc80000, 0x1dc80000)
  from space 13056K,   0% used [0x1dc80000, 0x1dc80000, 0x1e940000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x1e940000, 0x1e940000, 0x1f600000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 131072K, used 0K [0x1f600000, 0x27600000, 0x47600000)
 Metaspace       used 4546K, capacity 4713K, committed 4736K, reserved 5504K
Event: 1.230 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 13056K [0x17600000, 0x1f600000, 0x1f600000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x17600000, 0x17600000, 0x1dc80000)
  from space 13056K, 100% used [0x1e940000, 0x1f600000, 0x1f600000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x1dc80000, 0x1dc80000, 0x1e940000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 131072K, used 23534K [0x1f600000, 0x27600000, 0x47600000)
 Metaspace       used 4546K, capacity 4713K, committed 4736K, reserved 5504K
}

Deoptimization events (8 events):
Event: 0.410 Thread 0x01c1d000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x085b143c method=java.lang.String.replace(CC)Ljava/lang/String; @ 2
Event: 0.523 Thread 0x01c1d000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x085ce58c method=java.lang.String.startsWith(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z @ 25
Event: 0.789 Thread 0x01c1d000 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=make_not_entrant pc=0x08657fb0 method=java.util.zip.ZipUtils.get16([BI)I @ 10
Event: 0.821 Thread 0x01c1d000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x08681800 method=java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Ljava/util/jar/Manifest$FastInputStream;[B)V @ 17
Event: 1.310 Thread 0x01c1d000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x086a1e18 method=java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.reallyPoll()Ljava/lang/ref/Reference; @ 52
Event: 1.310 Thread 0x01c1d000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x086a1e18 method=java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.reallyPoll()Ljava/lang/ref/Reference; @ 52
Event: 1.310 Thread 0x01c1d000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x086a1e18 method=java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.reallyPoll()Ljava/lang/ref/Reference; @ 52
Event: 1.311 Thread 0x01c1d000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x086a1e18 method=java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.reallyPoll()Ljava/lang/ref/Reference; @ 52

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.178 Thread 0x01c1d000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x17736fa0) thrown at [D:\src\AOSP-openjdk-cygwin\jdk8u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1167]
Event: 0.374 Thread 0x01c1d000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x17ba6298) thrown at [D:\src\AOSP-openjdk-cygwin\jdk8u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.374 Thread 0x01c1d000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x17ba6678) thrown at [D:\src\AOSP-openjdk-cygwin\jdk8u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.375 Thread 0x01c1d000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x17ba90c8) thrown at [D:\src\AOSP-openjdk-cygwin\jdk8u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.375 Thread 0x01c1d000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x17ba94a8) thrown at [D:\src\AOSP-openjdk-cygwin\jdk8u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.375 Thread 0x01c1d000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x17baa478) thrown at [D:\src\AOSP-openjdk-cygwin\jdk8u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.375 Thread 0x01c1d000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x17baa858) thrown at [D:\src\AOSP-openjdk-cygwin\jdk8u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.395 Thread 0x01c1d000 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x17bd2a00) thrown at [D:\src\AOSP-openjdk-cygwin\jdk8u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 1.618 Thread 0x01c1d000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x1a8f4a30) thrown at [D:\src\AOSP-openjdk-cygwin\jdk8u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 1.642 Thread 0x01c1d000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': sun/dc/DuctusRenderingEngine> (0x1a9315b8) thrown at [D:\src\AOSP-openjdk-cygwin\jdk8u\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]

Events (10 events):
Event: 1.676 loading class sun/java2d/SunGraphicsEnvironment done
Event: 1.676 loading class sun/awt/Win32GraphicsEnvironment done
Event: 1.676 loading class sun/font/FontUtilities
Event: 1.676 loading class sun/font/FontUtilities done
Event: 1.676 loading class sun/font/FontUtilities$1
Event: 1.676 loading class sun/font/FontUtilities$1 done
Event: 1.676 loading class sun/java2d/windows/WindowsFlags
Event: 1.677 loading class sun/java2d/windows/WindowsFlags done
Event: 1.677 loading class sun/java2d/windows/WindowsFlags$1
Event: 1.677 loading class sun/java2d/windows/WindowsFlags$1 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x004df000     C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\bin\studio.exe
0x77cd0000 - 0x77e5f000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x77570000 - 0x77608000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x752f0000 - 0x754d6000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x72ef0000 - 0x72f8d000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
0x77690000 - 0x77805000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x754e0000 - 0x754fb000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x76f30000 - 0x76f52000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x74780000 - 0x748e7000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x75500000 - 0x7557d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x74bd0000 - 0x74cee000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x77610000 - 0x77688000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x75b20000 - 0x75bdf000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x76fc0000 - 0x77004000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x77c00000 - 0x77cc7000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x75be0000 - 0x76f2a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x752b0000 - 0x752e9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x77b40000 - 0x77bc8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
0x75820000 - 0x75a7c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x74b70000 - 0x74bc8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x74cf0000 - 0x752aa000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x77080000 - 0x770c5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x746e0000 - 0x746ef000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x74760000 - 0x74778000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
0x74710000 - 0x74755000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
0x74700000 - 0x74708000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\FLTLIB.DLL
0x77bd0000 - 0x77bf6000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x07ea0000 - 0x08483000     C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\jre\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x75580000 - 0x75586000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6ea70000 - 0x6ea78000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x71d50000 - 0x71d74000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x77010000 - 0x77077000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x702f0000 - 0x702f8000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x675a0000 - 0x6765f000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR100.dll
0x71d20000 - 0x71d43000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x70bd0000 - 0x70bdc000     C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\jre\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x54040000 - 0x54062000     C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\jre\jre\bin\java.dll
0x68630000 - 0x68643000     C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\jre\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x741a0000 - 0x741b3000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x73cc0000 - 0x73cef000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x742a0000 - 0x742bb000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x74620000 - 0x74641000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x741c0000 - 0x741ca000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x54480000 - 0x54495000     C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\jre\jre\bin\net.dll
0x74020000 - 0x74078000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x73e10000 - 0x73e40000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x75a80000 - 0x75a87000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll
0x6ef80000 - 0x6ef93000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x6ef60000 - 0x6ef74000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x550e0000 - 0x550ef000     C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\jre\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x52400000 - 0x52543000     C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\jre\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x779a0000 - 0x77a36000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x72560000 - 0x72a74000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d2d1.dll
0x669c0000 - 0x66a4f000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.17134.112_none_40fcc05845145445\COMCTL32.dll
0x73080000 - 0x730fc000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x756d0000 - 0x75814000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x73280000 - 0x732a3000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x77a40000 - 0x77b3c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
0x67380000 - 0x67502000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -da -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\lib\boot.jar -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true -Dide.native.launcher=true -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio3.1 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\Winfried\java_error_in_studio_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\Winfried\java_error_in_studio.hprof 
java_command: <unknown>
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\lib\bootstrap.jar;C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\lib\extensions.jar;C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\lib\util.jar;C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\lib\jdom.jar;C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\lib\log4j.jar;C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\lib\trove4j.jar;C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\lib\jna.jar;C:\Users\Winfried\Desktop\android-studio\jre\lib\tools.jar
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172
PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\;C:\Users\Winfried\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Winfried\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\Winfried\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin
USERNAME=Winfried
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 Build 17134 (10.0.17134.1)

CPU:total 2 (initial active 2) (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 3668396k(1585768k free), swap 7338412k(4759660k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK Server VM (25.152-b02) for windows-x86 JRE (1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02), built by "builder" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Tue Jun 26 22:32:28 2018
elapsed time: 1 seconds (0d 0h 0m 1s)
```

I also enabled small memory dump (128KB) in advanced system settings. Can someone please help me?